# how to get input value from the ng-repeat to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form that increases when the use click on the add sale button

this is the html

```
<fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">
            Quantity :
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="choice.quantity" ng-model="choice.amount" />
    </div>
```

how can I get the input value in my controller

```
appcat.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope',  '$location', function ($scope,  $location)
{
    // this controll the addition and removal
    $scope.choices = [{ 'amount': '' }]; 

    // I want to set the input field
        $scope.choice.amount = parseFloat(200* 4); // $scope.choice.amount and $scope.amount are not working


    // this generate a form
    $scope.addNewChoice = function()
    {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;

        $scope.choices.push({'amount': ''});

    };

    // this remove the form
    $scope.removeChoice = function () {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        if ($scope.choices.length > 1) {
            $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
        }
    };
}
```

how can I set the input value to this calculation `parseFloat(200* 4);` in my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might just be a typo in the code you've copied to stackoverflow, but the variable you should set is:

```
$scope.choices[0].amount = parseFloat(200* 4)
```

Or even shorter:

```
$scope.choices = [{ 'amount': parseFloat(200* 4}];
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would need to use ng-model :

From AngularDocs:

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel